# Mount point for specific USB port

Tags: linux, mount, usb

I have a USB hub connected to my laptop, always through the same port - my question is how can I make my linux installation always mount whatever is plugged into one of the specific ports on this hub be mounted to (e.g) /mount/left and likewise for the other port.

I know how I can do this for specific drives with the UUID of the drive, but I want it to be that case that /mount/left always refer to whatever is in the left port, whichever order different USB devices are plugged in.

Comment: I am doubting, whether this is possible. I do not think you can reliably infer port number from device number on an external USB-Hub after a few device (re-)connections leading to renumbering. Favorited.

Comment: You can do it with [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev), but you'll have to fight your way to it.  You'll need to run `udevadm info` to figure out attributes specific to each port of your hub, then write `udev` rules for them.  You probably want to look for `KERNELS` (not `KERNEL`).

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Just to clarify, this would be a permanently connected USB hub - I only use a hub because if I'm going to break USB ports by plugging things in and out over and over, I'd rather break the USB ports on a hub I can replace than on my laptop itself

Comment: `udevadm info  --name=/dev/sde` for example for a disc will provide a `ID_PATH_TAG` that should be a constant (eg `pci-0000_04_00_0-usb-0_2_1_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0`) that you can match in an udev rule.  You need to read up on `udisks2` and be very specific about your OS and version (especially systemd or not).

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I came across it while looking to do the same thing, and found a solution using fstab, see below:

First, plug in a drive to the port you want to map a mountpoint to. Use `sudo blkid` to get the /dev/sd** path to the drive & note this down/remember it. I'll be using '/dev/sda1'

Second, use `udevadm info --name=/dev/sda1 | grep disk/by-path`, which should give you a readout something like:

```
S: disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_Switch_4C530001110415101044-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-label/BACKUP_1 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/5936-F7EA
```

It's the `platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1` that we want. It might look fairly different depending on your device & hub. Copy it/note it down then open up fstab config `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and on a new line:

```
/dev/disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /media/card exfat auto,nofail,noatime,users,rw,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

replace `/media/card` with the mountpoint you desire, and make sure the bit following `/dev/disk/by-path/` matches what you copied earlier. The other options are variable depending on what you want.

Ctrl-X, Y, enter, to save fstab, then reboot and you should now have an auto-mounting usb port! You can repeat the previous steps for each port :)